# como recibir un objeto json con @RequestBody o @RequestParam

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

Ante todo pido disculpas, soy nuevo usando esta tecnología y la verdad tengo muchas dudas. Estoy tratando de enviar un objeto json a mi clase controlador el problema es que con @RequestBody llegando a todos los datos pero las claves foraneas alcanzadas null. Ejemplo ingresar un nuevo usuario con el id de un rol que ya existe en la BD, los datos del usuario completos pero el ID del rol llega nulo

Primero registre los datos del rol vía POST y todo funciona perfecto con @RequestBody, pero cuando intente registrar un usuario con el rol_id que ya está guardado en la base de datos igualmente usando @RequestBody se guarda con el id_rol null

Mi entidad usuario:

```
@Entity
public class Usuario implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    private String correo;
    private String pass;
    private boolean activo;

    @OneToOne(optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="rol_id", nullable = false)
    private Rol rol;

public Usuario(){}

public Usuario(String correo, String pass, boolean activo, Rol rol) {
        this.correo = correo;
        this.pass = pass;
        this.activo = activo;
        this.rol = rol;
    }
/*getter y setter*/
```

Mi entidad rol:

```
@Entity
//@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public class Rol implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    private String nombre;
    private boolean activo;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "rol")
    private List<Usuario> usuarios;

public Rol(){}

public Rol(String nombre, boolean activo, List<Usuario> usuarios) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.activo = activo;
        this.usuarios = usuarios;
    }
/*getter y setter*/
```

Repositorio del usuario:

```
@Repository
public interface UsuarioRepository extends JpaRepository<Usuario, Serializable> {
    public abstract Usuario findByCorreo(String correo);

}
```

Repositorio del rol:

```
public interface RolRepository extends JpaRepository<Rol, Serializable> {
}
```

Clase controlador de usuario:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1")
public class UsuarioController {

    @Autowired
    UsuarioRepository usuarioRepository;

    @PostMapping("/usuario/add")
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<String> crear(@Valid @RequestBody Usuario usuario) {
        try{
            usuarioRepository.save(usuario);
            return new ResponseEntity<String>("Registro Exitoso..", HttpStatus.OK);
        }catch (Exception e){
            return new ResponseEntity<String>("Ha ocurrido un Error..", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }
}
```

controlador de clase de rol:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1")
public class RolController {
    @Autowired
    RolRepository rolRepository;

    @PostMapping("/rol/add")
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<String> crear(@Valid @RequestBody Rol rol) {
        try{
            rolRepository.save(rol);
            return new ResponseEntity<String>("Registro Exitoso..", HttpStatus.OK);
        }catch (Exception e){
            return new ResponseEntity<String>("Ha ocurrido un Error..", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }

}
```

Esto es lo que envio a mi controlador:

```
{
  "correo": "pepito@gmail.com",
  "pass": "1234",
  "activo": "true",
  "rol_id": "5"
}
```

y esto es lo que recibo:

```
{
  "correo": "pepito@gmail.com",
  "pass": "1234",
  "activo": true,
  "rol_id": null
}
```

¿Como debo recibir este cuerpo con el id_rol = 5? Se que estoy haciendo algo mal en @RequestBody, Agradezco cualquier ejemplo que me pueda proporcionar ya que buscó y no he dado con eso. Gracias ..!

Comment: Prueba en la clase Rol cambiar private long id por private long rol_id o bien cuando mandes por HTTP no mandes rol_id sino id solo.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta.. es problema era que no estaba mandando el id del ro como lo que es, un objeto.

{
  "correo": "pepito@gmail.com",
  "pass": "1234",
  "activo": "true",
  "rol": {
    "id":"5"
  }
}

Comment: Hola Anderson, bienvenido! Si publicas la solución que comentas como respuesta a tu pregunta quizá sea más fácil de localizar para otros usuarios :-) Un saludo!